# Auditing a terribly designed database system in SQL 2000

Tags: sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2000

One of the most important databases that I administer is poorly designed. The program which uses it uses only 1 login which happens to be a System Administrator. Edits and deletes are done in place so change tracking is difficult.

Further, it lacks proper auditing functionality so I cannot tell which user edited or deleted a certain record.

I thought I might resort to using SQL triggers and output the record information along with information about the user who edited/deleted it. I can't use LoginName because the program only uses one login.

Can I export other information using a trigger such as the desktop machine name which sent the delete command?

Is there any other information that I could export that would assist me in this?

Answer (score 4):

You might look at the sys.sysprocesses table (sysprocesses in SQL Server 2000 I think).  It contains information that you normally see in the output of the sp_who2 stored procedure.  It includes hostname, which is the computer that is connecting to SQL Server.  Some of the other columns may be useful too.

Comment: +1. Was just about to answer with this `select hostname,program_name,nt_domain,nt_username,loginame from master..sysprocesses where spid=@@spid`

Comment: +1, the `HOST_NAME()` function can also be used to get hostname. This value may not be accurate (it's set by the client application), but it might be reliable enough for this.